# jquery datepicker using getDay and getDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

i am trying to pass the value of the variable "currentDate" to variable "day" such that  for whatever date the user selects i get the corresponding value in the getDay method,
example if the user selects a date 03/21/2018, ie value the  using the getDay should be '3'
implementation:, for every date selected i want the corresponding value using the getDay

**welcome.html**

```
{%  extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap %}


{% block content  %}
<title>welcome</title>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id = "demo1"></p>

        <script>
        var date = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
        </script>

    <form action = " " method = "GET" role="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{form|bootstrap}}
            <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
        var day = currentDate.getDay();
        window.alert(day);


    });
</script>

        </table>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <input type ="submit" value= "CHECK" class="form control"/>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style = "background-color:#9f9">
        <h1>Itam Market</h1>
    </div>

    <div style = "background-color:#0fc " >
        <h1>welcome please pick a date</h1>
        </div>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
    <hr>
    <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's not working ? is your `day` variable not good ?

Comment: yes, i added the window alert , to check if it actually return the getDay value, but it doesn't , there is no response or any return value